# What CDSSO implementation best resolves Disparate User database

Tags: cross-domain, single-sign-on, opensso

What Cross-Domain Single Sign-On implementation best solves my problem?

I have two domains (xy.com & yz.com) which already have their own database of users and are already implementing their user authentications separately. Recently there has been the need to implement CDSSO so that users dont have to log in each time they try to access resources from both domains.

Ideally the CDSSO implementation I hope to use should allow custom implementation of authentication, as I hope to call API's provided by both domains during authentication to confirm a user exists in at least one of the domains user database.

I've been looking at Sun's OpenSSO which seems to provide a means to extend its AMLoginModule class yet this seems to be a long thing and more annoyingly they seem to stick to GlassFish.

I've also considered developing a custom CDSSO to solve our needs. Is this advisable?

Is this achievable using Suns OpenSSO considering the disparate user database as I there will be no need to make use of the User db that OpenSSO requires?

Are there any simpler means of achieving what I intend to achieve?

In addition both applications which exist on the two domains were developed using PHP. How does this have an effect considering Suns OpenSSO is based on Java EE?

Are there any clearly specified steps on implementing OpenSSO and or any other SSO implementations from start to finish?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use simpleSAMLphp in order to deploy an Identity Provider and 2 Service Provider (for each app).

SimpleSAMLphp allows you to select multiple authentication source and is not hard to build your own authsource that consults the 2 databases.

My experience in SAML says that the fact of not consolidating the Identity of the user in 1 unique authsource is a bad idea due several reasons:
 * identity conflicts: what happen if you have the same user registered with different mail (if that is the field yoy use to identify the user) and you try to access? You could be logged in different account each time.
 * what happen if you add a 3rd service, do you gonna add a 3rd database
 * what happen if user change its data in one app, the other gonna be no synched?
 * what happen if user uses different passwords?

I recommend you to execute a migration process before adding the SAML support and build a unique database for all your identities and unify the registration/edit profile/password recovery process of both sites in one.

SimpleSAMLphp has good documentation, but I can provide to you any documentation related to the process that I suggested.

Comment: Ok, will look at this and get back to you. Thanks Smartin